# Get the dynamic number after the last "/" of external url

Tags: php, url-parsing

I want to grab the last dynamic numbers of an external URL.

`https://data.aboss.com/v1/agency/1001/101010/events/xxxxxx`

```php
$url = https://data.aboss.com/v1/agency/1001/101010/events/;
$value = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
```

```
value="<?php echo $value; ?>"
```

result should be xxxxxx.

Comment: where is the URL coming from?

Comment: Give two or more examples of URLs and the corresponding desired results. The code provided cannot result `xxxxxx `, since `$url` does not contain `xxxxxx `.

Comment: Hi fusion3k, what I am trying is to check if there are events. When its true the url is something like this ```https://data.aboss.com/v1/agency/1001/101010/events/1234567``` and when there are no events there is nothing after events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, the simplest one-liner would be to use explode:

```php
echo explode("/events/", $url)[1];
```

Or if something may come after 'events/xxxxxx':

```php
$url = "https://data.aboss.com/v1/agency/1001/101010/events/1524447/other/123456";
echo explode("/", explode("/events/", $url)[1])[0]; // 1524447
```

You can also use a regex with [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```php
$url = "https://data.aboss.com/v1/agency/1001/101010/events/1524447/other/123456";
$matches = [];
preg_match("~/events/(\d+)~", $url, $matches); // captures digits after "/events/"
echo($matches[1]); // 1524447
```

[Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io?s=pY7BCoMwEETvgv8Qggct4hqrLdSWfohKSXUxBzXBpNJe_PaaVqH3sjAww87bPV-VUK7jPcaOXAgVxih9Ami44RG_S62jWvYwMeAtDvULWByzRewATjgYDSxL0jQ9gjQCR2DJPs0ONHcdgH-oluA6WAtJ8Kk62aBPgYY_ZlsMib0TFKwKirgiEaHlYNtez00tUC8fFNXi1Yjt7ZP5dN7aftnsgnllLLp2gvx7298CS8_f&v=8.2.1)

Comment: This Works! Thank you very much Arleigh Hix!

Answer (score 0):

To get the last part from the url, you can use `parse_url()` and `pathinfo()` function in PHP. Try following code,

```
<?php
$url = "https://data.aboss.com/v1/agency/1001/101010/events/xxxxxx";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$value = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

echo $value;
```

Comment: Hi Irfan, thanks for your answer. Its working but it does not check the external url. The result is xxxxxxx but not the dynamic number of the url

Comment: I don't understand what is you mean by dynamic number? What do you expect the result in the mentioned url? Is not xxxxxx you want?

Comment: No it is something like 1524447 but its dynamic so what I need are the dynamic generated numbers after url/events/...

Comment: Ben you haven't said where this `$url` is coming from, I've tested the code posted here and it does indeed extract the part that comes after `events/`. Nothing in your question mentioned validating, and there is no way to get a number out of a URL that has no numbers. You should edit your question to provide more context and to specify the entire question with no hidden parts

Comment: Hi Tom, what I am trying is to check if there are events. When its true the url is something like this https://data.aboss.com/v1/agency/1001/101010/events/1234567 and when there are no events there ist nothing